# excel sheet sub headings as columns

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, heading

I am totally new to this kind of challenges and not sure any thing available ( not sure even on what base I have to search )

In the below excel sheet image the column 'A' has headings in two places ( row numbers 2,3 and 9,10) . The actual excel sheet has more than six thousand rows and too many sub headings like this ( If it is small file I can do it manually.. but more than 6 thousand rows)

The challenge :- I want to populate E column with "Make" value and F column with " Model" from sub headings . Can I write any rule or macro to populate these columns ? could some one help me ? Thanks for your help

[Image Link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/81362269.png/)

or below

[image]

[image]

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this solely in Excel you can use the following. This assumes

1. All Headings are the same for "S.No"
2. Change the SUBSTITUTE clause to match the text for Make and Model eg I have used exact spacing of `"Model: "` and `"Make : "` to match the spreadsheet and substitute with ""

In cell G5 Enter `=IF(ISNUMBER(A5),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Model",A3,1)),MAX($G$1:G4),MAX($G$1:G4)+1),"")`

In cell F5 Enter `=SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(A5),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($G5,$G:$G,0)-2,COLUMN(A1),1)),""),"Model: ","")`

In cell E5 Enter = `=SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(A5),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($G5,$G:$G,0)-3,COLUMN(A1),1)),""),"Make : ","")`

Then drag down the formula in E5:G5 to wherever you need. However, I only recommend using this once only as the formulae will be slow to update over large ranges. Also if your headings are out of sync then VBA is the way forward

[image]

Comment: Thanks lot osknows for this wonderful solution . It is working fine . But having a little bit problem . For some " MAKE , MODELS ", the customer information span across two pages and "S.NO " exists twice or thrice for the same " MAKE , MODELS " . Is there any to delete those column headings in between . I mean the case is " If the previews row value is number and  the current row value is "S.NO" delete that record . So that case the solution your provided works fine . Sorry for not covering this case in my question . BUT AGAIN THIS IS WONDERFUL SOLUTION

Comment: @Bujji - I'm not sure  I understand, can you give an example image of the problem?

Comment: Thank You @osknows and sorry for not explain it in detail. I updated my question and added the second image .If you look at the 8th row It has row heading repeating ( S.NO,Customer Name ...)  But these two rows also belongs to Same model and make ( GM and Pontiac) .So for the same MAKE AND MODEL CARS we can have more than one S.NO .

Comment: In fact I don't even require these sub headings in between ( If they are there or not doesn't matter ) . To make the things simpler I can delete them . But is there any automated approach to delete these ? The case is " If the previews row value is number and the current row value is "S.NO" delete that record"

Comment: @Bujji - I've updated the formula for G5 to work in this instance. Just copy down

Comment: @osknows - That was really wonderful . You saved my lot of time . Total 23 excel sheets and each sheet has more than six thousand rows . All worked great . Not sure how to appreciate your help . THANKS A LOT